# How to convert 2 Strings (date and time) into one NSDate object in Eastern Time Zone in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code to convert a String with a date like `April 22, 2017` and a second String with the time `4:30 PM` and I need to convert these 2 Strings into one complete NSDate object in the Eastern Time Zone.

```
//convert scheduled date and time from String to NSDate
let scheduledServiceDateStr = orderReview.serviceDate //current format example: April 21, 2017
let scheduledServiceTimeStr = orderReview.serviceTime //current format example: 04:30 PM
print("scheduledServiceDateStr: \(scheduledServiceDateStr)")
print("scheduledServiceTimeStr: \(scheduledServiceTimeStr)")


let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "EST")
let scheduledServiceDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(scheduledServiceDateStr)
print("scheduledServiceDate: \(scheduledServiceDate)")

let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
timeFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "EST")
let scheduledServiceTime = timeFormatter.dateFromString(scheduledServiceTimeStr)
print("scheduledServiceTime: \(scheduledServiceTime)")

let timeComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: scheduledServiceTime!)

let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: scheduledServiceDate!)

// append the time to the date
dateComponents.hour = timeComponents.hour
dateComponents.minute = timeComponents.minute
dateComponents.second = timeComponents.second

let dateAndTime = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
print("dateAndTime: \(dateAndTime)")
```

This is what is printed in the Console:

> scheduledServiceDateStr: April 22, 2017
>   scheduledServiceTimeStr: 04:30 PM
>   scheduledServiceDate: Optional(2017-04-22 05:00:00 +0000)
>   scheduledServiceTime: Optional(2000-01-01 21:30:00 +0000)
>   dateAndTime: Optional(2017-04-21 20:30:00 +0000)

The issue I am having is that the ending result, the `dateAndTime` NSDate value displayed in the console at the end is `2017-04-21 20:30:00 +0000` but, the time `20:30:00` I believe is equivalent to `8:30 PM` Eastern Time when the time originally selected was `4:30 PM`. I understand that NSDate does not take Time Zones into account and that it is just a representation of of seconds since January 1, 2001. As you can see I am setting the Time Zone to `EST` before converting each String to an NSDate object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the String you are parsing it is not local time?

Comment: Normally you just change the timezone when converting the date to string

Comment: Your code is fine. It is giving you the correct result. There is nothing to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the time. EST is -04:00 so `16:30 EST = 20:30 GMT`. And you wrote way more code that needed to be:

```
let scheduledServiceDateStr = "April 21, 2017"
let scheduledServiceTimeStr = "04:30 PM"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "EST")

if let date = formatter.date(from: scheduledServiceDateStr + " " + scheduledServiceTimeStr) {
    print(date)
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is right. Also, + string concatenation is slow. I would strongly recommend `"\(scheduledServiceDateStr) \(scheduledServiceTimeStr)"` instead

Comment: Note that the OP is using Swift 2

Comment: Thanks! I see now how 20:30 is in GMT. And also I see that can just concatenate both Strings and do it all in one step. Perfect! Changed it a little bit to conform to Swift 2. Working great.